# A refinement of Mittag-Leffler Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, analytic-functions

The Mittag-Leffler Theorem claims that given a discrete set $S \subset \mathbb{C}$ and principle parts at every $s \in S$, then we can find an analytic function $f: S- \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with $S$ as its set of poles and with the prescribed principle part.

There is a refinement of this theorem which states that we can prescribe for each $s$ not only the principle parts but also finitely many Laurent coefficients for non-negative indices. Under this condition, we can also construct $f$.

I have tried to construct a function which has the form
$$ \sum_{s \in S } \left( \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{b_{-n}^{(s)}}{(z-s)^n} - P_s(z) \right) (z-s)^{M_s}$$
where  $$(z-s)^{M_s} \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{b_{-n}^{(s)}}{(z-s)^n} $$ is the given restrictions. For example, we can choose for every $s$ a polynomial $P_s(z)$ such that for any $|z| < \dfrac{1}{2} s$, $$\left( \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{b_{-n}^{(s)}}{(z-s)^n} - P_s(z) \right) (2|s|)^{M_s}$$ is sufficiently small, so that the sum converges for all $z$.

I do not find any problems with my proof, but I'm still afraid that it is fake. Also, are there any other approaches to the proof of this theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Say the condition is simple poles of residue $r_n$ at the $a_n,n\ge 1$ where $|a_n| \le |a_{n+1}| \to \infty$

For each $|a_n| > 1$ take $K_n$ such that $r_n/ 2^{K_n} \le 1/n!$ and let $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{r_n}{z-a_n} -P_n(z),\qquad \qquad P_n(z)=\frac{r_n}{-a_n} \sum_{k=0}^{K_n} (z/a_n)^k$$ 
Can you find if it converges and it is meromorphic ?

Comment: Well, your discussion seems to be restricted to the original theorem. I understand that by taking suitable $K_n$ then for any $z$, each term in the series is bounded by $C \dfrac{1}{n!}$ so it converges. Probably I do not describe my question clearly, but I would like to know whether my solution to the "general" theorem is correct.

Comment: I think what I wrote is quite the only solution to the theorem, do you think there is a different one ?